# How to theme a paragraph bundle with a template file?

Tags: 7, theming, paragraphs

I am using the [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) module version `7.x-1.0-beta6` I have a bundle with the machine name: `text_buttons`

In the paragraphs module there are two theme suggestions:

```
 paragraphs-items.tpl.php
 paragraphs-item.tpl.php
```

if I copy `paragraphs-items.tpl.php` to my template folder under my theme, i can modify the code and see the changes reflect site wide wherever there is a paragraph bundle.

Now when I go to target a specific `paragraph bundle` nothing happens at all.
I've followed the solutions in the following threads:

- https://www.drupal.org/node/2326443
- https://www.drupal.org/node/2481339
- https://www.drupal.org/node/2399631

Nothing seems to work. Is the module currently broken? do I have to implement some sort of theme hook? I've made sure to flush caches on every change just to ensure I would be seeing the template file but it doesn't work, I've never had a problem with finding theme names before.. The documentation is non-existent for this module, and i really don't want to dig into the module code right now.

Another thing to note is that `paragraphs-item.tpl.php` does nothing on my website from either the module or my theme directory. it seems only `paragraphs-items.tpl.php` works out of the box.

I've tried:

```
paragraphs-items--text-buttons.tpl.php
paragraphs-items--text_buttons.tpl.php
paragraphs-items-text-buttons.tpl.php
paragraphs-items-text_buttons.tpl.php

field--paragraphs-items--text-buttons.tpl.php
field-paragraphs-items--text-buttons.tpl.php
field--paragraphs-items--text_buttons.tpl.php
field-paragraphs-items--text_buttons.tpl.php

field--paragraphs-items-text-buttons.tpl.php
field-paragraphs-items-text-buttons.tpl.php
field--paragraphs-items-text_buttons.tpl.php
field-paragraphs-items-text_buttons.tpl.php
```

**Anyone have an idea why I can't theme my paragraph bundles?**

Comment: Mind accepting my answer?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same question. Here's what worked for me with: Drupal 7.41, Paragraphs 7.x-1.0-rc4.

1. Go to the end of your settings.php file and remove the hash sign to enable
   "$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;" Or add the line if not present.
2. Flush your cache.
3. With your favorite browser, inspect the Paragraph output that you
   want to override. You should now have HTML comments, just before the
   actual markup, with template filename suggestions that you can use
   in your theme.

With my setup, the template filename suggestions are:

```
paragraphs-items--{field name}--{view mode}.tpl.php
paragraphs-items--{field name}.tpl.php
paragraphs-items.tpl.php
```

Where field name is the name of the field you use when you assign the paragraph field to a content type (**not the Paragraph bundle name**).

So in your particular case, if the paragraph field happened to be named "text-buttons" (machine name "field_text_buttons"), the filename suggestions are:

```
paragraphs-items--field-text-buttons--full.tpl.php
paragraphs-items--field-text-buttons.tpl.php
paragraphs-items.tpl.php
```

Don't forget to turn off theme debugging on your production site.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 3):

You were soo close, but there is no `s` in `item` when using bundle.

**paragraphs-item--[bundle-name].tpl.php**

so for you:

paragraphs-item--text-buttons.tpl.php

---

You can add the view mode if you want:

paragraphs-item--[bundle-name]--[view-mode].tpl.php

Comment: You don't have some samples handy to illustrate (give inspiration to people like me ...) how you could actually use that "view-mode"? Just a wild guess (not such if it makes sense): for any view mode different from view mode X, only show some type of reduces/condensed version of the paragraph. Or do you think this would be woth a "real" question I should post (so that you have more room to post a specific answer)?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I think you answered your own question. You can use the view mode to target a specific view (ie: teaser) and print different paragraph fields or the give div wrappers different classes.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the [Edgy](https://www.drupal.org/project/edgy) module installed the template prefix is `edgy-`.

So in your case it would be `edgy-paragraphs-item--text-buttons.tpl.php`

**Edgy:**

> Edgy allows site builders to display Paragraph items edge-to-edge. It does this by controlling the placement of the .container [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container) class.
>
> Using a combination of Paragraphs, Panelizer and Edgy, site builders can create powerful edge-to-edge landing pages. Bootstrap is not a requirement and any theme can be used, however, just make sure you have a container class which centers content.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that theming paragraphs-item does not work as the theming function for a paragraph_item is never actually called:

> Paragraphs includes a theme template declaration for paragraphs-item,
>   however the ParagraphItemEntity class never uses this, instead it
>   passes the rendering to EntityAPIController, which uses #theme =
>   'entity'.
>
> This is probably acceptable, but the theme declaration should be
>   removed if that is the case.

from bug in paragraphs module: [Paragraphs never calls #theme paragraph_item](https://www.drupal.org/node/2394519)